# How to force start/stop service in sharepoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server

i want to start a service "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service " by using the following power

```
$ServiceName = "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service"
Get-SPServiceInstance -server $env:COMPUTERNAME | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq $ServiceName} | Start-SPServiceInstance -confirm:$false > $null
```

The status is stuck in Starting for a hour which it seems not working. I have tried iisrest, restart window.

Is there any way to force stop it?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to force the status update of the Service Instance. But it is also important to check the Windows Service, as the Sandbox Service has one.

```
$si = Get-SPServiceInstance -Server SERVERNAME | ?{$_.TypeName -match 'sandbox'}
$si.Status = 'Offline'
$si.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way to stop it:

> $ServiceName = "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code
>   Service"
>
> Get-SPServiceInstance -server $env:COMPUTERNAME | where-object
>   {$_.TypeName -eq $ServiceName} | Stop-SPServiceInstance
>   -confirm:$false > $null

After that, if you still can’t start this service, open the services window in server and check if the SharePoint User Code Host is running. And add the Service Account used for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service with Full Control rights.

References:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Start-Stop-the-8df0fd6d
http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2016/08/14/enable-sandbox-solutions-on-sharepoint-2016/

Comment: i granted the service account to local admin group. Don't know is this enough for your Full Control rights to execute the service.